# Can I make Super Search an inclusive search?

Tags: solspace, supersearch

Super Search Version 2.1.4, Expression Engine Version 2.8.1

Right now Super Search is running what I would call an "exclusive search".

That is, if I search for "dogs and cats", I will only return entries that contain in searchable fields the words "dogs", "and", AND "cats". It will not return results for entries that just the terms have "dogs" AND "cats" but not "and", nor will it return results for entries that only contain the terms "dogs" AND "and".

Is it possible to make Super Search inclusive, so that if I search for "dogs and cats", I will return results for entries that contain "dogs" OR contain "cats" OR contain both "dogs" AND "cats".

If I can set up Super search this way, can I prioritize results that contain more of the search terms. In the above example, could I make entries that have both "dogs" AND "cats" appear higher than results that only have "dogs" OR "cats"?

EDIT: Here is the {exp:super_search:results} portion of our search template.

```
    {exp:super_search:results
        channel="products"
        limit="12"
        show_future_entries="yes"
        search_in="title|product_display_title|product_author|product_sku|product_isbn"
        search_words_within_words="yes"
        allow_repeats="no"
        paginate="bottom"
        fuzzy_distance="2"
        fuzzy_weighting="yes"
    }

        {if super_search_no_results}
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p>No results matched your query.</p>
            </div>
        {/if}

        {if super_search_total_results==1}
            {redirect="product/{url_title}"}
        {/if}

        {if count == 1 OR count == 4 OR count == 7 OR count == 10}

        <div class="ad-col m-bottom">
            <div class="row ">

        {/if}
                <div class="col-md-4 ad-small">
                    <div class="well bg-1 ad-col-height">
                        <h4><a class="inherit-hyperlink" href="{url_title_path=product}">{title}</a></h4>
                        <div class="row m-top">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <a href="{url_title_path=product}"><img class="img-responsive" src="{if product_thumbnail}{product_thumbnail}{if:else}/media/products/noi.jpg{/if}" alt="{title}"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                {if product_tag!="" AND product_tag != "None"}
                                    <p class="{product_tag}">{product_tag:label}</p>
                                {/if}                           
                                {if product_author}<p><small>By {product_author}</small></p>{/if}
                                <p>Product Code: {product_sku}
                                <br />Price: {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}" disable_form="yes" disable_javascript="yes"}{price}{/exp:store:product}
                                <br />{if product_binding != "Other"}{product_binding}{/if}</p>
                                <p><a href="{url_title_path=product}" class="btn btn-default">View Details</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /.row -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 m-top">
                                {product_short_description}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- /.well -->
                </div><!-- /.ad-small -->

        {if count == 3 OR count == 6 OR count == 9 OR count == 12 OR count == total_results}
            </div><!-- /row -->
        </div>
        {/if}

        {paginate}

        <div class="text-center">
        {pagination_links}
        <ul class="pagination">
        {first_page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-first">&laquo;</a></li>
        {/first_page}

        {previous_page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-previous">&lt;</a></li>
        {/previous_page}

        {page}
        <li {if current_page}class="active"{/if}><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-{pagination_page_number} ">{pagination_page_number}</a></li>
        {/page}

        {next_page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-next">&gt;</a></li>
        {/next_page}

        {last_page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-last">&raquo;</a></li>
        {/last_page}
        </ul>
        {/pagination_links}
        </div>

        {/paginate}

    {/exp:super_search:results}
```

Comment: What version of Super Search are you using? Can you show your template case, at least the parameters that you are using? You could also put "and" in Super Search's "Ignore Wordlist" (CP) to ignore it. Also, this doc page on relevance ordering is a good read: http://www.solspace.com/docs/super_search/relevance_ordering/

Comment: I'm running Super Search Version 2.1.4 and ExpressionEngine Version 2.8.1 right now. The word "and" exists by default in the Ignore Wordlist, but I was just experimenting, and it doesn't seem to be working. I added the {exp:super_search:results} code so you can see what I haave so far.

Comment: Here's an actual great example of this from out website: The search "2012 international plumbing code book" returns zero results, even though we have a product entry named "2012 ICC International Plumbing Code (IPC), Loose Leaf". How can I have that product appear for that search query? I feel like if I could make Super Search an inclusive search, it would fix much of that issue.

Comment: So "2012 ICC International Plumbing Code (IPC), Loose Leaf" is the entry title, or in a specific custom field part of your list `title|product_display_title|product_author|product_sku|product_isbn`? Did you also set those fields as searchable? Also, `inclusive_keywords=""` is set to `yes` by default. Perhaps try `no` (based on the "dogs and cats" search)?

Comment: "2012 ICC International Plumbing Code (IPC), Loose Leaf" is both the "title" and the "product_display_title" on that list of searchable fields, so it is searchable.

Comment: Also, I didn't realize there was an inclusive paramater. Is it inclusive_keywords="no", or is it inclusive="no"? Now my concern is that if I turn inclusive off, I might get too many results. Could I set the number of word matches to include? In other words, could I set it up so that if I search "dogs and cats", I will only get results that contain at least two of those words?

Comment: As mentioned in the docs, it's `inclusive_keywords="no"` (http://www.solspace.com/docs/super_search/results/#inclusive_keywords) This needs to be set to `yes` is you want dogs AND cats. Set it to `no` if you want dogs OR cats or both. Besides `inclusive_keywords="no"`, there's `where=""` which is similar but overrides inclusive_keywords. Docs about that are here: http://www.solspace.com/docs/super_search/results/#where

Comment: If you're having trouble searching even in an entry title, try clearing your Super Search cache and rebuild the index lexicon form the Super Search CP.