# Is it posible to use symbols in Super Search's Ignore Wordlist?

Tags: solspace, search, supersearch

Super Search Version 2.1.4, Expression Engine Version 2.8.1

Some searches have come through our website with "&" or "®", and because of these symbols, these search terms produce zero search results. I've tried using Super Search's built-in Ignore Wordlist, but it doesn't seem to stop these symbols from ruining the search.

Please note that, so far, it seems that the ignore wordlist currently is not working with regular words. For example, one of the default ignored words is "and", but searches with "and" in the search still ignore products that do no contain the word "and". I even tried setting use_ignore_word_list="yes" in the search template, but it had no effect. Please Advise.

EDIT: Here is the {exp:super_search:results} portion of our search template.

```
    {exp:super_search:results
        channel="products"
        limit="12"
        show_future_entries="yes"
        search_in="title|product_display_title|product_author|product_sku|product_isbn"
        search_words_within_words="yes"
        allow_repeats="no"
        paginate="bottom"
        fuzzy_distance="2"
        fuzzy_weighting="yes"
    }

        {if super_search_no_results}
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p>No results matched your query.</p>
            </div>
        {/if}

        {if super_search_total_results==1}
            {redirect="product/{url_title}"}
        {/if}

        {if count == 1 OR count == 4 OR count == 7 OR count == 10}

        <div class="ad-col m-bottom">
            <div class="row ">

        {/if}
                <div class="col-md-4 ad-small">
                    <div class="well bg-1 ad-col-height">
                        <h4><a class="inherit-hyperlink" href="{url_title_path=product}">{title}</a></h4>
                        <div class="row m-top">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <a href="{url_title_path=product}"><img class="img-responsive" src="{if product_thumbnail}{product_thumbnail}{if:else}/media/products/noi.jpg{/if}" alt="{title}"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                {if product_tag!="" AND product_tag != "None"}
                                    <p class="{product_tag}">{product_tag:label}</p>
                                {/if}                           
                                {if product_author}<p><small>By {product_author}</small></p>{/if}
                                <p>Product Code: {product_sku}
                                <br />Price: {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}" disable_form="yes" disable_javascript="yes"}{price}{/exp:store:product}
                                <br />{if product_binding != "Other"}{product_binding}{/if}</p>
                                <p><a href="{url_title_path=product}" class="btn btn-default">View Details</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /.row -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 m-top">
                                {product_short_description}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- /.well -->
                </div><!-- /.ad-small -->

        {if count == 3 OR count == 6 OR count == 9 OR count == 12 OR count == total_results}
            </div><!-- /row -->
        </div>
        {/if}

        {paginate}

        <div class="text-center">
        {pagination_links}
        <ul class="pagination">
        {first_page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-first">&laquo;</a></li>
        {/first_page}

        {previous_page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-previous">&lt;</a></li>
        {/previous_page}

        {page}
        <li {if current_page}class="active"{/if}><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-{pagination_page_number} ">{pagination_page_number}</a></li>
        {/page}

        {next_page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-next">&gt;</a></li>
        {/next_page}

        {last_page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-last">&raquo;</a></li>
        {/last_page}
        </ul>
        {/pagination_links}
        </div>

        {/paginate}

    {/exp:super_search:results}
```

Comment: Can you show your template code? Also, the latest version of Super Search is 2.2.1 as of this writing. I would backup your data/files and update to this version. Trying to ignore the `&` is tricky for Super Search, since it's used by the add-on in some search strings. As for the "and" question, it's likely related to this: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/26905/can-i-make-super-search-an-inclusive-search

Comment: Can I change the value of super_search_keywords using PHP in the template? I've been experimenting with this:
 <?php
  str_replace ("-", "", 'super_search_keywords')
 ?>

Comment: Any reason to do this? This is possible, but parse order can be complicated. Also, use `'{super_search_keywords}'`, not `'super_search_keywords'` in your PHP, or else EE won't parse this as a variable.

Comment: I have just updated to Super Search 2.2.1, and the "Ignore Wordlist" still has no effect on searches whatsoever. Please advise.

Comment: Also, after over 1500 searches, most plurals and misspellings are still not returning their singular or correct equivalent results. These are simple plurals, for example, "residential codes" should hit results that contain "residential code", but it currently does not. Still, the bigger issue seems to be that the Ignore Wordlist is not functioning.

Comment: I am still having an issue with the Ignore Wordlist. Is there anything that could be causing this?